# How to configure Spring-Security to access user details in database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am puzzled with SpringSecurity. There are many ways to implement a simple thing and I mixed them all up.

My code is as follows but it throws exception. If I remove `UserDetailsService` related codes, the application runs and I can login `in-memory` users. As suggested below, I converted the configuration to XML based but users cannot sign-in.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could 
not autowire field:  
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService 
com.myproj.config.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying 
bean of type    
[org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for 
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for 
this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),  
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userDetailsService)}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
autowire field 

org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService 
com.myproj.config.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 
[org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] 
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire 
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), 
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userDetailsService)}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 
[org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for 
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for 
this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), 
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userDetailsService)}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>proj</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>proj</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

**MvcWebApplicationInitializer**

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer
    extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer**

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
                passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/", "/index", "/aboutus")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/profile/**")
                .hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/signin").failureUrl("/signin?error")
                .permitAll().and().logout().logoutUrl("/signout").permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception        
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

**MemberServiceImpl**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MemberServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    MemberRepository memberRepository;

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(String role) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        List<GrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(
                setAuths);
        return result;
    }

    private User buildUserForAuthentication(Member member,
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(member.getEmail(), member.getPassword(),
                member.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Member member = memberRepository.findByUserName(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority("Role");
        return buildUserForAuthentication(member, authorities);
    }

}
```

**Update 1**

Even after adding following annotation, and `authenticationManagerBean` method from SecurityConfig the same exception is being thrown.

```
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

**Update 2**

As suggested in one of the answers, I converted it to XML based configuration, the current code is as following;however, when I submit login form it does not do anything.

**Spring-Security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">



    <beans:import resource='login-service.xml' />
    <http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/notFound.jsp"
        use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />


        <form-login login-page="/signin" authentication-failure-url="/signin?error=1"
            default-target-url="/index" />
        <remember-me />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <!-- <user-service> <user name="admin" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/> 
                <user name="user" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER"/> </user-service> -->
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

                users-by-username-query="
              select username,password,enabled 
              from Member where username=?"

                authorities-by-username-query="
                      select username 
                      from Member where username = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**login-service.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testProject" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: How are you picking up the `@Service` annotation on `MemberServiceImpl`? Typically you would add a `@ComponentScan `annotation to pick that up. If you have added it, please include all package names for the configuration with `@ComponentScan` and for `MemberServiceImpl`.

Comment: Try this : http://www.sivalabs.in/2014/03/springmvc4-spring-data-jpa.html

Comment: @prtk_shah that tutorial made it too complicated. Do you know of any better one?

Comment: @DanielNewtown +1 for your question.. if u need further more help comment on me.

Comment: @DanielNewtown Do you want my code in github..shall i upload

Comment: @MSIbrahim I would highly appreciate it if you could share a link.

Comment: @DanielNewtown Ok..Here is the link. We have a downloadable project also. Any errors and doubt comment on me..http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/02/spring-security-login-form-using.html#.VeBZfZdMmf5 .

Comment: All database requirements are on that link itself

Comment: appreciate that will check that out.

Comment: Here you can download bunch of Spring security jar files. Dont use different version jar files for spring and spring security..use same version.. u can download here..http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/security/

Comment: @MSIbrahim sorry I forgot, I will give you a bounty of 200 as well if it solves my problem.

Comment: Keep commenting on me.. I will solve your issues

Comment: @DanielNewtown hey comment on me if u have any doubts.. only 14hrs left

Comment: @MSIbrahim I am still wiring it up. What do you mean by 14hrs left?

Comment: thats bounty ending time

Comment: @MSIbrahim do not worry about that, if your solution solves my problem I will offer you another bounty :)

Comment: There is no need to switch to xml. Java configuration looks much nicer, switching to xml just to solve an issue is silly and an indicator that you got no clue what you're doing. So did you get your problem solved yet? I see some good replies here but I'm currently on mobile, if this is not solved by tomorrow I'll post a working example. Good luck.

Comment: @prettyvoid thanks for your comment, I switched to xml-based in hope of resolving this issue quicker as I am dealing with it for a long time now, also, I used to work with XML based security last year but I almost forgot many parts of it. I thought might remember it all but not yet.; however, I am still having different issues. I could not find a working example!!!, and it drives me crazy. It would be highly appreciated if you would give me a working example so I can figure out how it works and what I was doing wrong! It seems like almost 19 people are looking for the same result as well.

Comment: @DanielNewtown Not sure about the exact issue you are facing now, but try adding the port number in the DB URL. Change `jdbc:mysql://localhost/testProject` to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testProject` (or whatever port you are running the application on).

Answer (score 19):

I think you forget for add this annotation on SecurityConfig  Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
                passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/", "/index", "/aboutus")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/profile/**").hasRole("USER").and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/signin").failureUrl("/signin?error")
                .permitAll().and().logout().logoutUrl("/signout").permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

and one things more I thinks this bean is not need

```
 @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
```

Please try this hope this will work for you..

For get current user

```
public String getUsername() {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null)
            return null;
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            return ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            return principal.toString();
        }
    }


    public User getCurrentUser() {
        if (overridenCurrentUser != null) {
            return overridenCurrentUser;
        }
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(getUsername());

        if (user == null)
            return user;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you could add some explanations to your answer for me to better understand your code.

Comment: Sure,By using @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity we can easily secure our methods with Java configuration. Note that methodSecurityService is not really part of our Security configuration, but we must create our MethodSecurityService using Spring so that it can have Security applied to it.

Comment: If you want to get current login user from spring security then you use this method  .I have update our answer

Comment: I added that annotation but it still throws the same exception.

Comment: have you remove authenticationManagerBean bean?

Comment: yes I did then cleaned the project and ran it again.

Answer (score 16):

I think the issue could be due to missing `@ComponentScan` annotation. When trying to autowire `userDetailsService` in `SecurityConfig`, it's not able to find a suitable bean to autowire with.

A spring application usually has a separate "application context", in addition to "mvc context", "security context" (which you already have via `SecurityConfig`), etc.

I'm not sure if putting `@ComponentScan` on `SecurityConfig` itself will work on not, but you can give it a try:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("your_base_package_name_here")
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

Replace "your_base_package_name_here" with the name of the package containing your `@Component` or `@Service` classes.

If this doesn't work, add a new, empty class with `@ComponentScan` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("your_base_package_name_here")
public class AppConfig {
    // Blank
}
```

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html

Answer (score 6):

See there are some errors exist in your code base try to resolve it by seeing the code below.

Remove your SecurityConfig file and convert into xml file based configuration.

Your spring-security.xml should look like this.

```
   <security:http auto-config="true" >  
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER" />  
  <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index"  
   authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" />  
  <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />  
 </security:http>  

    <security:authentication-manager>  
   <security:authentication-provider>  
     <!-- <security:user-service>  
   <security:user name="samplename" password="sweety" authorities="ROLE_USER" />  
     </security:user-service> -->  
     <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"    
      users-by-username-query="select username, password, active from users where username=?"   
          authorities-by-username-query="select us.username, ur.authority from users us, user_roles ur   
        where us.user_id = ur.user_id and us.username =?  "   
  />  
   </security:authentication-provider>  
 </security:authentication-manager>
```

web.xml should be looking like this:

```
 <servlet>  
  <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
 </servlet>  

 <servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>  
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
 </servlet-mapping>  
 <listener>  
  <listener-class>  
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener  
        </listener-class>  
 </listener>  

 <context-param>  
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
  <param-value>  
   /WEB-INF/sdnext-*.xml,  
  </param-value>  
 </context-param>  

 <welcome-file-list>  
  <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>  
 </welcome-file-list>  

 <!-- Spring Security -->  
 <filter>  
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
  <filter-class>  
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy  
                </filter-class>  
 </filter>  

 <filter-mapping>  
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
 </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following method to your SecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
    return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring cannot find the bean with qualifier `userDetailsService`.
I think you should check your `applicationContext.xml` file in case if you have forgot to configure `UserDetailsService`'s bean for Spring Security.If it there then try once by removing `@Qualifier("userDetailsService")`.

follow this link.
[context.xml file configured against spring security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/xml/jwt/src/main/resources/context.xml)

Answer (score 2):

It seams that your "userDetailsService" bean is declared **@Autowired**, but it's not available as a class (*MemberServiceImpl*) in the context of your *SecurityConfig*.

I suppose in your *MvcWebApplicationInitializer* you should include *MemberServiceImpl* also like:

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class, MemberServiceImpl.class };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the field type:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    MemberServiceImpl userDetailsService;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer , using the proper @ComponentScan will resolve, below is sample code snippet I am pasting which I also faced the same problem and resolved. Below is solved and works for issue related to bean creation exception for ***org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService***

---

**Step1:** Write the Security Application Configuration class

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

Here @ComponentScan is not mandatory in *LoginSecurityConfig*  , you can define @ComponentScan in the root config class like below and import the **LoginSecurityConfig.class** LoginSecurityConfig.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" })
@Import(value = { LoginSecurityConfig.class })
public class LoginApplicationConfig
```

**Step2:** Now Autowiring the SpringBean ***org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService***

```
@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserDao userDao;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);

if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("User not found");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
}


  return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    return authorities;
}

    }//End of Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Wicket and ran into the same problem. 
I could solve this problem by changeing the order in my AppInit Class to scan the package first, then register the calling Bean

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException 
{

        // Create webapp context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        root.scan("my_package");
        root.register(SpringSecurityConfiguration.class);
...#
}
```